# How to disable special handling of calling convention examples in emacs-lisp-mode?

Tags: emacs, clojure, elisp, docstring

As described [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Documentation.html#Function-Documentation), emacs-lisp-mode provides for special handling of s-expressions in docstrings that start in the first column.  This requires them to be escaped with a backslash to avoid mucking up font-lock later on in the file.

This may be a feature for elisp, but is unfortunate in other lisp modes that reuse emacs-lisp-mode for convenience that don't have special handling of expressions in docstrings, as described/shown [here](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clojure-mode/issues/183).

My question is, is there any way for such "descendant" modes to configure emacs-lisp-mode to disregard "calling convention expressions" in docstrings?

Comment: I'm sure I've red about the option you can turn on, and it will cause Emacs to parse Lisp syntax not relying on convention that the open parenthesis in the first column starts a new definition. But this parsing is a lot slower then the conventional one. I really just got used to formatting them in the way I don't put the paren on the first column :)

Comment: Yup, found it: `C-h v open-paren-in-column-0-is-defun-start`

Comment: @wvxvw After some experimentation with large Clojure files (e.g. core.clj in Clojure itself), and files that contain very large sexpressions (e.g. the single large sexp the [core_test.cljs](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/master/test/cljs/cljs/core_test.cljs) file in ClojureScript), I've found setting that option to nil yields exactly the behaviour I want, with little to no perceptible perf penalty on various editing operations, paredit motions/changes, etc.  If you offer it as an answer, I'll accept. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many Emacs programming modes, and various Lisp modes are no exception, have been implemented based on parsers with regular expressions. This, unfortunately, gives the editor little idea of the document being edited. Eclipse, for example, has a very different idea of how to edit code, which is more structured, and JetBrain MPS editors are even more rigid and structured in this sense (almost like spreadsheets).
This makes Emacs modes faster and easier to implement, but it also means the code that supports the proper indentation, syntactic validation and highlighting has to re-parse more text every time it is being edited. CEDET, afaik, is trying to address this issue.

Thus, historically, there had been conventions designed to reduce the amount of code to parse on each edit. Parenthesis in the first column is one such convention. However, it also has been known to be an annoyance some times, that's why there's a `open-paren-in-column-0-is-defun-start` variable one can set to `nil` to inhibit this behaviour.

But It's hard to say what exactly the performance issues you may face when changing this setting. Lisp grammar is very regular, unless you are using many reader macros, so, perhaps, that won't be a problem.

Comment: Clojure doesn't offer reader macros, so that's not a problem.  My experimentation with `(setq open-paren-in-column-0-is-defun-start nil)` in my `init.el` has been very successful.  (The 0-column open paren/bracket/brace is still colored improperly, but it no longer breaks paredit or negatively affect coloration later on in the form/file, which is a fine outcome AFAIC.)  Parsing/rendering perf seems unaffected AFAICT, based on some experimentation with very large Clojure files/forms.  Thanks!

Comment: @ChasEmerick not the custom ones, although I think I've heard something about it being worked on, perhaps some experimental version. But there are surely built-in ones, `#"[a-z]"` would be a regular expression iirc.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.

The longer answer is that those other modes are simply broken.  They should adapt to Emacs Lisp in this regard.  There is no reason not to, is there?  It is simply a bad idea to use workarounds (e.g. indent all doc-string lines), such are suggested in the link you provided (and its linked duplicate post).

Emacs doc string are *not* trivial strings. They have several special properties, including the handling of `\\[...]`, `\\{...}`, and `\\<...>`, as well as the property you mention here.

If some mode *cannot* adjust to Emacs doc strings then it should use macros that define the things it needs without creating Emacs doc strings for them but by handling a different string argument in the special way desired.  IOW, create pseudo doc strings that correspond to what the mode wants instead of what Emacs wants.

Of course, that means that you cannot *directly* take advantage of the Emacs documentation features. You would need to also define mode-specific doc commands that would, for example, wrap the existing doc functions such as `describe-function` with code that picks up the mode's pseudo-doc string and DTRT, following the mode's conventions instead of the Emacs doc-string conventions.

But I would think that the easiest approach would be to just adapt the mode to the existing Emacs behavior, so that it DTRT.

Comment: Seems impractical / wrong. Clojure (for example) is not emacs-lisp, and code styles shouldn't adjust to conform its expectations.  e.g. Clojure docstrings are clojure strings, so if you escape a paren, the backslash(es) will appear in generated documentation, doc popups, etc.

Comment: "Clojure docstrings are..." ***not Emacs*** doc strings, which is my point. Let Clojure (mode) define its own notion of doc strings. That definition should not implement itself as simply Emacs doc strings. A more sophisticated implementation is called for, if you want something different from Emacs doc strings. IOW, either you want to leverage Emacs doc strings, in which case you should recognize what they are, or you don't, in which case you should roll your own. (This is true of any language feature, BTW.) If you expect something different then it is up to you to build something different.

Comment: As I see it, your alternatives are (1) ugly little workarounds such as indenting or rephrasing, to avoid putting parens etc in column 0, (2) implementing a different sort of doc string for Closure mode, to better fit Closure, or (3) living with the mismatch between the two notions of doc string: Closure & Emacs. Just do not expect Emacs to provide Closure doc strings out of the box. That's all.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification. I thought you were suggesting that Clojure docstrings are just "wrong", and that Clojure programmers should adopt emacs conventions.  Sorry for the misunderstanding on the internet. :-)  My question, then, is: can you point me in the general direction of how I might add a different handling of docstrings to clojure-mode?  Or, is it likely that basing it on elisp-mode doesn't leave enough wiggle room in this area (and maybe others)? FWIW, I'm ~an emacs noob, though hardly new to lisps or lisp tooling.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this either. I tried to suggest some possibilities (macros to define functions, which accept the kinds of strings you want and handle them properly; implementing your own help functions, that build on the Emacs ones). But (a) I have no idea what other, better approaches there might be -- let's hope others can give you good ideas here, and (b) from what I can see, such an undertaking would not be trivial.  If it were I (and I'm not very familiar with Clojure), I would probably not bother and would just make do with Emacs doc strings. IOW, it might be a lot of work to DTRT.

Comment: I think we're talking past each other a bit, i.e. I don't get what you mean re: "using macros" (Clojure's primary definition forms _are_ macros), but in any case, I'm not willing to change coding styles to suit the emacs-lisp mode. Anyway, the option that @wvxvw offered seems to work quite well on the largest files/sexpressions I know of off the top of my head.  Thanks for the input on the "right way". :-)

Comment: I meant only that a function-defining macro can accept a form as argument that contains a string which can be a Clojure doc string. The generated function definition can DTRT, so that the result of defining the function gives Closure -- and gives your Emacs Closure-specific help functions (TBD) -- the info they need. `open-paren-in-column-0-is-defun-start` is what it is. If it helps, go for it. Just be aware that it has more effect on Emacs than just this `){[`-in-coloumn-0-for-doc-strings thing, as @wvxvw mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If beginning-of-defun-function is set accordingly, i.e. checking if inside a comment or string, should be no need for such escaping.